# Class Method Not Recognized

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've attempted to add a method onto my class but it is being recognized as a property rather than a method??

#### shape.ts

```
export class Shape {
   color: string;
   size: string;

   constructor() {
     this.color = 'Green';
   }

   getColor() {
     return this.color;
   }
}
```

#### mock-data.ts

```
import { Shape } from './shape.ts';

export const shapeList: Shape[]= [
  {color: 'Red', size: 'Large'},
  {color: 'Orange', size: 'Medium'},
  {color: 'White', size: 'Small'}
]
```

#### Error

```
ERROR in src/app/mock-data.ts(5,14): error TS2322: Type '{ color: string, size: string}' is not assignable to type 'Shape[]'.
  Type '{ color: string, size: string}' is not assignable to type 'Shape'.
    Property 'getColor' is missing in type '{ color: string, size: string}'.
```

Answer (score 2):

`getColor` is not optional, so it would be required in each `Shape` array element. You could declare an array of [partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#partial-readonly-record-and-pick) `Shape`s (a generic class with optional properties of `T`) with `Partial<Shape>`:

```js
const shapeList: Partial<Shape>[]= [
  {color: 'Red', size: 'Large'},
  {color: 'Orange', size: 'Medium'},
  {color: 'White', size: 'Small'}
];
```

[demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Shape%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20color%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20size%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20this.color%20%3D%20%27Green%27%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20getColor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.color%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20shapeList%3A%20Partial%3CShape%3E%5B%5D%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%7Bcolor%3A%20%27Red%27%2C%20size%3A%20%27Large%27%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7Bcolor%3A%20%27Orange%27%2C%20size%3A%20%27Medium%27%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%7Bcolor%3A%20%27White%27%2C%20size%3A%20%27Small%27%7D%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A)

Answer (score 2):

As @tony19 said, `getColor` isn't optional - it's a property on `Shape` that the compiler is expecting when it casts each of the objects in the `Shape[]` to `Shape`.  An alternative to using `Partial<T>` might be to make `color` and `shape` members of the `Shape` class that are set when a `Shape` instance is instantiated:

```
class Shape {
  constructor(private color: string, private size: string) {
    this.color = color;
    this.size = size;
  }

  getColor() {
    return this.color;
  }

  getSize() {
    return this.size;
  }
}

const shapeList: Shape[]= [
  new Shape('Red', 'Large'),
  new Shape('Orange', 'Medium'),
  new Shape('White', 'Small'),
]

for (const shape of shapeList) {
  console.log(shape);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use static getColor(), but you don't really need it as you can directly acces your object values.

In general we use a static method to parse or adapt an object to your class

Comment: A static method cannot access instance members (i.e., `static getColor()` cannot read `this.color`)